# Is there an R function to summarize individual level data by country and year?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I am trying to make country-level (by year) summaries of a long-form aggregated dataset that has individual-level data. I have tried using dplyr to summarize the average of the variable I am interested in to create a new dataset. However... there appears to be something wrong with my group_by because the answer is only one observation that appears to be the mean of every observation.

data named: "finaldata.giniE",
country variable: "iso3c",
year variable: "date",
individual-level variable of interest: "Ladder.Life.Present"

Note: there are more variables in my data-- could this be an issue?

```
country_summmary <- finaldata.giniE %>%
  select(iso3c, date, Ladder.Life.Present) %>%
  group_by(iso3c, date) %>%
  summarize(averaged.M = mean(Ladder.Life.Present))

country_summmary
```

My output appears like this:> country_summmary

averaged.M

1   5.505455

Comment: it might be that there is summarise from some other package, try puting `dplyr` in front of function: `dplyr::summarise()`. It's always good idea to go through pipe step by step to find where error (or something you dont expect) occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you!

I actually just changed something and added your suggested code to the front and it worked! Here is the code that was able to work!

```
library(dplyr)
country_summary <- finaldata.gini %>% 
                     group_by(iso3c, date) %>% 
                     select(Ladder.Life.Present) %>% 
                     summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Comment: well , I meant changing `summarize(averaged.M = mean(Ladder.Life.Present))` in your code to  `dplyr::summarize(averaged.M = mean(Ladder.Life.Present))`. Don't you get an error by putting just `dplyr::summarise()` in your code?

Comment: As det suggests, the line `dplyr::summarise()` is not doing anything. The reason this new version works is because `summarise_each` is a unique function only present in `dplyr`. The offending package is often `plyr`, but you can find all functions that export `summarise` using `getAnywhere(summarise)`.

Comment: Oh thank you both very much! I do have plyr in my libraries, I imagine that is it! I am sure that was what was running! Sorry for the confusion about where to put dplyr::summarise()